# Oracle Apex: Auto select if shuttle list contains only a single item

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a shuttle list that, depending on the selection of a previous form, may have between one and seven items. Is there any way for me to automatically move the entry to the right hand pane if there is only a single selection, just for the sake of long term optimization and user friendliness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like sim0n's answer. But here's another that uses JavaScript (you can choose which is best for your use case).

1. Create a Dynamic Action. Set **Name** to **Page loaded** and **Event** to **Page Load**.
2. Select the Action created by default. Set **Action** to **Execute JavaScript Code**, then enter the following code in **Code**.

   ```
   var itemId = 'P1_ITEM_NAME';
   var $opts = $('#' + itemId + ' select:eq(0) > option');

   if ($opts.length === 1) {
     $s(itemId, $opts.val());
   }
   ```

   Don't forget to change the name of the item to match the one on your page.

When the page loads, the JavaScript will check to see how many options are in the select element on the left. If there's just one, it will set the value of the item using the value to the value of the single option.

Comment: I had to change the trigger from "Page Load" to "Change" but this works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a default Value to your shuttle item

```
SELECT YOUR_COLUMN_ID
FROM T0000_YOUR_TABLE
WHERE FILTER_COLUMN_ID = :P_FILTER_ITEM_PREV_FORM
GROUP BY YOUR_COLUMN_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

If there are more than 1 entries for your filter item the statement will return nothing, if there is exactly 1 entry the entry will be returned and set for your shuttle item

Comment: this looks nice